How add tailwindcss in to vue using typescript?
How add tailwindcss in to vue using typescript?
I have run "vue add tailwindcss" and got this error
ERROR  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\VueJS\TS\e-commerce\src\main.js'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\VueJS\TS\e-commerce\src\main.js'
I just use "vue create " to create the app, not use "vite". Who can help me?

vue create is for Vue2 no? Try that one rather: https://github.com/vuejs/create-vue

I fixed it, Vue fast create is easy to get this error when add s.th is not cmd of Vue support, so that I create custom Vue and select all part I need, and its work.
